# Modifying Aesthetics - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to learn **ggplot2** and have made below plots:

[image]

Using this code:

```
library(ggplot2); library(gridExtra)
gg <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Level))
plot1 <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=Experience,colour="xp"),size=1) +
    labs(title="xp") 
g <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Level))
plot2 <- g + geom_line(aes(y=Experience,colour="xp"),size=1) + geom_line(aes(y=Accu,colour="accu"),size=1) +
    labs(title="xp vs Accumulated") 
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

Where `mydata` is a data frame containing 3 columns (`Level`, `xp` and `accu`) and 30 rows.

What I am wondering is:

1. How to get the y-axis on the left-hand plot to have the same form as the
   right-hand plot.
2. How to make the color of "xp" the same in both plots
       without removing the descriptions of what the lines represent.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (with some random data)?

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(gridExtra)
library(scales)

gg <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Level))
plot1 <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=Experience,colour="xp"),size=1) +
  labs(title="xp") + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +   
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red"))

g <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Level))
plot2 <- g + geom_line(aes(y=Experience,colour="xp"),size=1) + 
   geom_line(aes(y=Accu,colour="accu"),size=1) +
   labs(title="xp vs Accumulated")  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + 
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))

grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: To ensure that the colors match the appropriate level, you can also do something like the following: `scale_colour_manual(values = c("accu" = "blue", "xp" = "red"))`.  This should ensure the level is matched with the desired color.